# Using the HTML5 Video tag with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, mime-types, create-react-app

So I have this code

```
export default () => {
    return (
        <main>
            <section className="section-home">
                <div className="bg-video">
                    <video className="bg-video__content" src="./video/pn-video.mp4" autoPlay loop>
                        <source src="./video/pn-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                        <source src="./video/pn-video.webm" type="video/webm" />
                        Your browser is not supported!
                    </video>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
    )
}
```

In the Video.js file of this project 'https://codesandbox.io/s/py2ryvrkrx' you can see it works just fine without create-react-app. However, everywhere (both local and in codesandbox) I've tried to use create-react-app Firefox shows this in the console "HTTP “Content-Type” of “text/html” is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:3000/video/pn-video.mp4 failed." and I can't for the life of me figure out how to add more mime-types.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I do have my import statement. I just copied the function to save some space.

Comment: import ./video/pn-video.mp4 like this : import myVideo from './video/pn-video.mp4 ';   and use it <source src={myVideo} type="video/mp4" /> ;  try this once and let me know

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked once I loaded it into my original <source> tags. Much appreciated. And now that I've run the inspector and see what's going on I've learned something!

Comment: did that worked ? are you facing any other problems ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in `src/utils.d.ts` and add this content:

```
declare module "*.mp4" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

Then you can import your `.mp4` as any other file in your react components:

```
import videoMp4 from "../../assets/video.mp4”;


<video autoPlay loop muted playsInline>
  <source src={videoMp4} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```